# Android Custom Launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am building an kid mode app. In my app the an activity called KidModeActivity (this is an launcher to prevent kid from getting out of the activity)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.KidModeActivity"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

KidModeActivity has android:enabled="false". To get into kid mode, I will enable that activity then create a launcher picker for the users

```
ComponentName launcherActivity = new ComponentName(this, KidModeActivity.class);
                    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(launcherActivity,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                // Create launcher chooser
                Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                startActivity(selector);
```

I can choose my custom launcher
When in custom launcher:

- Home button is ok when pressed
- Back button is ok
- But I can still press recent button and see my app there (!!!), I can swipe to close my app too

Anyone helps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible. You will need android.permission.REMOVE_TASKS for that and it's only granted for system apps.

Comment: Hi @Anupam, can you tell me how to implement launcher like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mindquake.nester

In that app, after choosing some apps for kids, when people click "GO TO KIDMOD" button

A launcher chooser will appear - just the first time (choose Nester launcher as "always")
After using the app, people have to do nothing but exit and the previous launcher (Ex: Asus default launcher) is set programmatically
The next time people use this Nester app, the Nester launcher is already set (no launcher picker)

Answer (score 0):

In previous android version there was `Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS` which you could run to check for recent app drawer list and then run this intent to close any such system dialogs. But it also closes power button dialogs and other system dialogs. Also would not work from Android Lollipop and above.

So you need to run a background service and a task that always checks if the top activity running is your app or any app you have allowed in your homescreen. If not then run your Home activity i.e: KidModeActivity.

To get top activity in Lollipop device you need to allow your app to get Usage Status and get top activity

```
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService("usagestats");
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
// We get usage stats for the last 40 seconds
List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 40, time);
```

If your app requires pre-lollipop device support then get top activity using getTasks.